# Find the Fourier transform for this function

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform, integral-transforms

> Find the Fourier transform for this function
>
> $$f(x)=e^{x-e^x}$$

My Solution:-

$T[f(x)]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ikx} f(x)dx$
$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ikx}e^{x-e^x} dx$
$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (e^{x})^{-ik}e^{x}e^{-e^x} dx$

let $u=e^x$ then $du=e^x dx $ , $u$ from $ 0 \to \infty  $

$T[f(x)]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} (u)^{-ik}e^{-u} du$
$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} (u)^{(1-ik)-1}e^{-u} du=\frac{\Gamma(1-ik)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

> Is this true solution?
>
> Is there a simplification of the final answer

Please, help me

Thank you for your participation

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  How much simpler did you want it to be?

Comment: $\Gamma(1-ik)=??$

Comment: The Gamma function is defined in the complex plane by analytic continuation except at its isolated poles.

Comment: *Mathematica* says  that Fourier transform for this function is $\frac{\Gamma(i\omega+1)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$.  $\Gamma(i\omega+1)=\Gamma(1-i\omega)$ ?

Comment: So , my answer incorrect ? @ vito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
T[f(x)]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i k x} f(x) d x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i k x} e^{x-e^{x}} d x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(e^{x}\right)^{-i k} e^{x} e^{-e^{z}} d x
$$
let $u=e^{x}$ then $d u=e^{x} d x, u$ from $0 \rightarrow \infty$
$$
T[f(x)]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty}(u)^{-i k} e^{-u} d u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty}(u)^{(1-i k)-1} e^{-u} d u=\frac{\Gamma(1-i k)}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}
$$